# Arduino serial event not returning

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project and would like to receive some commands from the `Serial port` with the arduino Serial event. However it always won't fulfill a condition, making the code not knowing the serial event has been finished. Here is my code.

```
void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    if (inChar == '`')
    {
        // add it to the inputString:
        inputString += inChar;
        // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
        // so the main loop can do something about it:
        if (inChar == '|') {
            settingsReceived = true; // <----- This will never be called
            Serial.println("true"); // <------ Nor this will too
        }  
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried passing the string `` `Hello| `` from the serial monitor yet it won't respond. Additionally, I've tried the `Line ending` with `No Line Ending` and `Newline` yet it won't work, Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured the problem, `Serial.read()` will only read a byte per time, for example, `` `Hello| `` will be split into

```
` H e l l o |
```

So for the first time, the `if (inChar == '```')` is true, therefore entering the actions inside, however from the second char, (H, e, l, l, o, |) are not the char "`", meaning `if (inChar == '```')` is not true, not letting it to enter the condition after that.

Here should be the propoer way of doing it:

```
void serialEvent() {
    if (Serial.available())
    {
       char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
       if (inChar != '`')
       {
         return;    // <----- Rejecting the char if not starting with `
       } 
    }

    while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
      char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    // add it to the inputString:
      inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
      if (inChar == '|') {
        settingsReceived = true;
        Serial.println("true");
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: have fun, its a nice little piece of hardware!

Answer (score 1):

Is `inputstring` being defined in the sketch?  Also, `loop()` and `setup()` have some tasks to complete.  See: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent this page has a good starting example, get it to work first and then modify it for your specific code.

When you type "Hello|" and press enter, what is the '|' for?  Is there a reason why you are NOT testing for '\n' as the line termination character?

Also, you are testing for inChar == '`' and then adding it to string, but you are typing in "Hello"? Serial I/O passes one character at a time, so you need to allow the inChars that are typed in.

Comment: hi @JackCColeman, `inputstring` has been defined globally, I'm following the example already... The example will work fine however after modifying as shown, it will not work...

Comment: Thank you for helping out, i've figured the problem out and please kindly review the answer! Thanks!!!